# endless vertical scrolling background

Tags: iphone, background, cocos2d-iphone, scroll

I want to make an endless vertical scrolling layer that gives the impression that the main character is moving upwards. I have been brainstorming on how to achieve this.
My issue is that I want objects to appear as if they are coming from above and below the screen at the same time. Secondly, I want to be able to move the main character to create and destroy box2d joints between it and some of the objects appearing on the screen. What is the best way to achieve this with consuming too much memory? I would appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Apple did a wonderful tutorial of this in a WWDC 2011 video session. It was "[UITableView Changes, Tips & Tricks](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=125)" and it's about 35m40sec into the video.

Since the use of the `UITableView` is really just a `UIScrollView` for the purposes of the background, you could just use a `UIScrollView` and you can either have it move on timer or events as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Think of your player as moving within a stationary bounding box. The background can scroll using the aforementioned pooling method (as the background tile scrolls off the screen it is placed into a pool, and before a new tile is instantiated the pool is checked for available reusable tiles). Thirdly, your enemy objects will simply approach from either the bottom of the screen or the top.

Imagine your idea without the scrolling background (flying effect) and you should find that the problem is relatively straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

I also needed and endless scrolling background layer. [This](https://github.com/aramkocharyan/cocos2d) can do exactly that, and it is super simple to set up and use. Just copy the four files in to the cocos2d folder in your project, then follow the quick tutorial seen on the github. Make sure the image you use is seamless (when you line them up vertically you can't tell where one ends.